# Is there a way of performing a function call when a MutableState of variable changes in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a variable called `currentlySelectedJobId`, this allows me to capture the job Id when the user has selected it elsewhere in my code.

When this happens i would like to scroll my `LazyRow` of items to this object.

```
LazyRow(state = scrollState) {
items(....
......
}
```

However I am struggling to see a way to capture the change of `currentlySelectedJobId` and perform the action `scrollState.animateScrollToItem(index = 0)`

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) with your variable as a `key`: it'll be called each time the `key` is different since latest recomposition.

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(currentlySelectedJobId) {
    scrollState.animateScrollToItem(index = 0)
}
```

This will also be called on the initial recomposition too, so depending on your code you may need to skip this initial call.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
@Composable
fun List(
currentlySelectedJobId: Int, //Pass a 'delegated' MutableStateValue here
state: //... The last scroll state
){
 LaunchedEffect(currentlySelectedJobId){
  state.animateScrollToItem(currentlySelectedJobId)
 }
}
```

`LaunchedEffect` here is used to trigger a function only once per composition or when the key changes. I passed the key as the job id (assuming it is the same as the index), then animated to that value.

You can read more about LaunchedEffect and other [side-effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)